# Should I hot link to facebook images when using their API or copy them to my server?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Should I hot link to Facebook images when using their API or copy them to my server?

What does Facebook want me to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Policy 2.2](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) states:

> "You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in
>   order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should
>   try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any
>   rights to such data."

You are free to cache the data on your side if you would like, but there was a [post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=62559) in their forum about this which stated hot-linking would be better.  If its just profile pictures, and not album photos, just use the [graph address photo](http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture).

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can link to facebook images:

http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture

Keeping images on your server has considerable overhead and also it is very difficult to up to time.

The only drawback of linking to facebook images is slightly delay while user load your page