# facebook api save user avatar

Tags: php, facebook, api

Performance wise, what would be the best? To save the Facebook avatar picture on loading in my own database or just constantly requesting the graph.facebook/x/picture ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to hot link to facebook instead of keeping on your server:

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100525/492258